# CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter

Tags: swift, xcode

When my project build success and finished launch, the console output as below:

```
2021-07-06 17:28:28.913313+0800 YueTime[44591:286098] [TraitCollection] Class CKBrowserSwitcherViewController overrides the -traitCollection getter, which is not supported. If you're trying to override traits, you must use the appropriate API.
```

macOS 10.15.7
Xcode12.2(12B45b)
Swift 5.1

[image]

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667516):

> The same thread was here and not specific to SwiftUI but this warning can be safely ignored according to Apple if it's a system class like "CKBrowserSwitcherViewController". However, if the class that produces is a custom class, then it's a legit warning to you.

By the way, it's a good idea to update Xcode to the latest version.